# Adding Casablanca Dependency VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, casablanca

I recently upgraded to VS2017 and I'm looking to start doing more C++ work. I've not used VS or C++ in a good while (and even at that I was a C++ novice).

I'm trying to install Casablanca, aka CPPRestSdk (https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) but I can't seem to manage it.

I've tried installing it through NuGet but I'm not sure exactly what I've to link to my project, and I've tried vcpkg - to which I've downloaded via the instructions but I have no clue what to do there.

All the materials I find for this apply to earlier VS editions and don't appear to work when I try them. Has anyone had such luck with getting this to work? If not, is there an alternative that I can use that has clear installation instructions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recently moved a C++ REST SDK based project from the older NuGet package to the recent VCPKG based 2.10.1 release. Apart from Visual Studio 2017 with the C++ for Desktop workload make sure you have [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/) installed. Clone the VCPKG repo from GitHub with

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg
```

I'd recommend using a directory not having any spaces in its path, otherwise some builds might fail. Change into the VCPKG directory and run the bootstrap script:

```
.\bootstrap-vcpkg.cmd
```

This will compile the package manager itself. Afterwards you can install the C++ REST SDK with

```
.\vcpkg install cpprestsdk cpprestsdk:x64-windows
```

This will download all required libraries and takes quite a while. For usage in Visual Studio you have to enable the system wide integration with

```
.\vcpkg integrate install
```

This requires elevated privileges the first time but afterwards the C++ REST SDK is available in any Visual Studio C++ project. Follow the instructions for [getting started](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial). As soon as you include a C++ REST SDK header into your project the linking is taking care of automatically by Visual Studio.

For consumption in a CMake project you have to pass the VCPKG toolchain file to the CMake command, e.g.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake
```

Referencing the C++ REST SDK from CMake is described in the project repo's [README](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/README.md).